# RecyclerView: Highlight selected item

Tags: android, cab, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a `RecyclerView` and I have set it up to use `CAB`. But how can I highlight the selected items? If a certain position I checked I stored in a `SparseBooleanArray`.
My first thought was to store the specific `View` containg all the elements in my `ViewHolder` and then in `onBindViewHolder` set the background somehow to: `?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator`
But how can I do that? Is that a useful approach?

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this by simply adding some minor things:

First of all, **the items** of the RecyclerView have to use this as background:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

Then for the RecyclerView simply call:
[setSelected(true);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSelected%28boolean%29) on the indiviual views.

Comment: can you please write the full code? It did not work for me

Comment: @Paul Woitaschek can you provide any code how you solved it please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the View itself, you need to dispatch adapter.notifyItemChanged(position) and in return, recycler view will call onBind method where you can set the background.

If you don't need to update the view itself, I would suggest using an item decorator.

Comment: What you mean with not need to update the view itself? How can I decorate a single item in a view with item decorator? And how can I set the background with android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator?